# Find out if PHP ran out of memory

Tags: php, memory-management, out-of-memory

Is it possible to find out (programmatically) if the current PHP process is about to run out of memory?

**Some Background**:

I am the author of the [Bulk Delete WordPress plugin](http://sudarmuthu.com/wordpress/bulk-delete), which allows people to delete posts, users etc in bulk.

One common complaint I get from my plugin users is that they get a blank page when trying to delete huge amount of posts. This happens because PHP runs out of memory.

If I can find out that the PHP process is about to run out of memory, then I can try to delete in batches or at least give a warning to the user, instead of just throwing a blank page.

Comment: "If I see that's it's going to crash, I can do something differently..." - Why don't you do it differently from the beginning? I don't see an inherent reason why this kind of process would need to use a lot of memory to begin with.

Comment: @deceze My plugin needs to retrieve records from DB and that's where it mostly runs out of memory. Before retrieving those records, I will have no idea about the size of the returned records. Also my plugin code will be run in various servers with different configuration. So I  can't just limit the number of rows that will be returned based on the available memory.

Comment: Sure, still, if you *can* do it differently, why don't you do it differently regardless of memory already consumed? I guess you're cramming all records into memory at once - you don't have to do that, do you?

Comment: Well, I have to use built-in WordPress functions. So I don't have too much control on how to retrieve or store the records in memory expect to specify how many I can retrieve. I tried to see if I can somehow do it differently, but there don't seem to be any other option in this case. That's why I wanted to know if I can detect this programmatically.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't allow you to say `get these 10 posts` ... `now these 10 posts` ... `now these 10 posts` ... ?

Comment: Well, the direct answer is: not really. Once PHP runs out of memory, there's nothing more you can do, because you're already out of memory. You can't know *when* you'll run out of memory if you can't even estimate how much data you're going to get. So the only and best thing you can do is to change your algorithm to use as little memory as possible from the beginning.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yeah WordPress allows it. But I will not know what would be the total number of posts (100 or 100,000). So I wouldn't be able to decide whether I should delete by 10 or 100 or 1000 in one step.

Comment: @deceze Okay, in that case, I think I should try to see if there are other options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more research I found a solution. The solution is to use [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

One drawback is that this function will get executed *after* PHP ran out of memory and not *before* (which is still fine with me, since I can just let the users know about it)

Comment: Thanks. I wish you could add some more info into your answer. What exactly did you do on shutdown to detect if your plugin ran out of memory? Did you use error_get_last()? As it is, your answer does not fully answer your question, and I don't see any mention of "shutdown" after grepping your plugin's source.